Format of int32_t in sscanf in C
I need to read (with sscanf) integer number that fits uint32_t. This number is given in hexadecimal base. What format should I use to read and print such number?

Why not strtoul() instead of sscanf?

@i486 It's best to learn how to do things the hard way.  So you never do it again. ;-)

You have special macros in the header file inttypes.h
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void)
{
    uint32_t x;
    if(scanf("%" SCNx32, &x) == 1)
    {
        printf("Scanned successfully. The value is %" PRIx32 "\n", x);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("scanf error\n");
    }
}


And similarly for sscanf().

Minor, IMHO, as function names are case sensitive, better as printf("scanf error\n"); or printf("Error: scanf()\n");
